# Design Special Layout for Nexus 5 Dimensions

Tags: android, layout

I want to design spesific layout for Nexus 5 dimensions. Because it is working with xxhdpi but this layout also working in pixel 3A. Therefore I want to design a layout and it will just work Nexus 5 dimensions ? How could I do it ?

Comment: That is akin to saying that you are going to create a Web design for a 1024 x 768 window size, plus a Web design for 1025 x 768, for 1026 x 768, ..., for 1024 x 769, for 1024 x 770, ... There are 26,000+ Android device models, spanning a range of resolutions and densities. You need to create 1-2 layouts that can handle a range of sizes between them, not create layouts for individual device models.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Actually we are talking same things. I have already layout that works other devices. However, there is a problem in 5" phones thats why I sad Nexus 5. In the other inches or devices it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, but a Nexus 5 should not require a different layout than a Pixel 3a. Those phones are very similarly sized. If you feel that those two require different layouts, then you will need thousands of layouts, as there are thousands of phones around that size. Layout should be density-independent, as the things that vary by density are handled elsewhere (drawables, dimension resources, etc.).